# Test the web site on mobile using appium

Tags: android, selenium, appium

I want to use Appium to test the web site on mobile. I have setup following thing

1. Latest Appium
2. Android SDK
3. TestNG
4. Java-client 2.1
5. Java1.7
6. Selenium 2.42 and selenium standalone 2.42

Environment variable is set for tools and platform-tools, Java and appium
Appium is starting but when i hit http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/ i got this message :

```
"That URL did not map to a valid JSONWP resource"
```

and on Appium window i saw this

```
Responding to client that we did not find a valid resource
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/ 404 24.032 ms - 47
```

After this i try to execute my script "Run as TestNG" i am getting this error:

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass setUp
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.<init>    
(Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/ErrorCodes;Z)V
```

and also nothing showing in appium window. My script is:

```
    AppiumDriver driver = null;
    capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "Appium");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.0.3");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "HTC Desire C");
    capabilities.setCapability("udid", "<Device No>");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "Browser");
    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(200, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The issue raising from

```
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Please help if any one also face this issue:

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How have you resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be because you are trying to set the udid as one of the capabilities for the Android Driver. UDID is only needed for iOS and should not be set at all when automating for Android.

For Android, just set a deviceName (this can be anything as long as you have just one Android device connected).